# Function or sub to add new row and data to table

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a Sub that basically allows me to target an Excel table with a specific name and then insert a new row at the bottom and add data to that row at the same time. Then exit the sub. And if the table only has one row with no data in it, add the data to that row and then exit the sub.

How can I do this?

I was thinking something like this, in pseudo code:

```
Public Sub addDataToTable(ByVal strTableName as string, ByVal strData as string, ByVal col as integer)

ActiveSheet.Table(strTableName).Select
If strTableName.Rows.Count = 1 Then
    strTableName(row, col).Value = strData
Else
    strTable(lastRow, col).Value = strData
End if

End Sub
```

This is probably not valid as code at all, but it should explain what I'm after at least!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub addDataToTable(ByVal strTableName As String, ByVal strData As String, ByVal col As Integer)
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim iHeader As Integer

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(strTableName)
        'find the last row of the list
        lLastRow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(strTableName).ListRows.Count
        'shift from an extra row if list has header
        If .Sort.Header = xlYes Then
            iHeader = 1
        Else
            iHeader = 0
        End If
    End With
    'add the data a row after the end of the list
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lLastRow + 1 + iHeader, col).Value = strData
End Sub
```

It handles both cases whether you have header or not.

Comment: I believe ActiveSheet.ListObjects(strTableName) can be ommitted as you're inside a With statement

Comment: @ColmBhandal you are probably right, should be tested though because the `With`statement behavior can be suprising sometimes ;)

Comment: Indeed I agree. Testing is a must! ;)

Answer (score 27):

I needed this same solution, but if you use the native [`ListObject.Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174248(v=office.11).aspx) method then you avoid the risk of clashing with any data immediately below the table.  The below routine checks the last row of the table, and adds the data in there if it's blank; otherwise it adds a new row to the end of the table:

```
Sub AddDataRow(tableName As String, values() As Variant)
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Range

    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set table = sheet.ListObjects.Item(tableName)

    'First check if the last row is empty; if not, add a row
    If table.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
        For col = 1 To lastRow.Columns.Count
            If Trim(CStr(lastRow.Cells(1, col).Value)) <> "" Then
                table.ListRows.Add
                Exit For
            End If
        Next col
    Else
        table.ListRows.Add
    End If

    'Iterate through the last row and populate it with the entries from values()
    Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
    For col = 1 To lastRow.Columns.Count
        If col <= UBound(values) + 1 Then lastRow.Cells(1, col) = values(col - 1)
    Next col
End Sub
```

To call the function, pass the name of the table and an array of values, one value per column.  You can get / set the name of the table from the `Design` tab of the ribbon, in Excel 2013 at least:
[image]

Example code for a table with three columns:

```
Dim x(2)
x(0) = 1
x(1) = "apple"
x(2) = 2
AddDataRow "Table1", x
```

Comment: Can you explain how to format the values you pass to the sub as a `Variant`?

Comment: I also added an `else` to the `If Count > 0` condition so that if the table is empty it will simply call `table.ListRows.Add`.  Seems to work fine.

Comment: this is great :) I was just looking for something like this

Answer (score 8):

Minor variation of phillfri's answer which was already a variation of Geoff's answer: I added the ability to handle completely empty tables that contain no data for the Array Code.

```
Sub AddDataRow(tableName As String, NewData As Variant)
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Range

    Set sheet = Range(tableName).Parent
    Set table = sheet.ListObjects.Item(tableName)

    'First check if the last row is empty; if not, add a row
    If table.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
        If Application.CountBlank(lastRow) < lastRow.Columns.Count Then
            table.ListRows.Add
        End If
    End If

    'Iterate through the last row and populate it with the entries from values()
    If table.ListRows.Count = 0 Then 'If table is totally empty, set lastRow as first entry
        table.ListRows.Add Position:=1
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(1).Range
    Else
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
    End If
    For col = 1 To lastRow.Columns.Count
        If col <= UBound(NewData) + 1 Then lastRow.Cells(1, col) = NewData(col - 1)
    Next col
End Sub
```

Comment: Enigma [15 14 ...]

Comment: Very vague on my part, use of the phrase 'minor variation' in both answers got me thinking about Elgar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GbD20h8-_4

Answer (score 6):

Minor variation on Geoff's answer.

New Data in Array:

```
Sub AddDataRow(tableName As String, NewData As Variant)
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Range

    Set sheet = Range(tableName).Parent
    Set table = sheet.ListObjects.Item(tableName)

    'First check if the last row is empty; if not, add a row
    If table.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
        If Application.CountBlank(lastRow) < lastRow.Columns.Count Then
            table.ListRows.Add
        End If
    End If

    'Iterate through the last row and populate it with the entries from values()
    Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
    For col = 1 To lastRow.Columns.Count
        If col <= UBound(NewData) + 1 Then lastRow.Cells(1, col) = NewData(col - 1)
    Next col
End Sub
```

New Data in Horizontal Range:

```
Sub AddDataRow(tableName As String, NewData As Range)
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Range

    Set sheet = Range(tableName).Parent
    Set table = sheet.ListObjects.Item(tableName)

    'First check if the last table row is empty; if not, add a row
    If table.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
        Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
        If Application.CountBlank(lastRow) < lastRow.Columns.Count Then
            table.ListRows.Add
        End If
    End If

    'Copy NewData to new table record
    Set lastRow = table.ListRows(table.ListRows.Count).Range
    lastRow.Value = NewData.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: how do I use adding new data in Horizontal Range, if I have multiple rows. Problem I have is it only adds first row to table. `Set rng1 = destSh1.Range("A7:AD7", destSh1.Cells(LastRowDestSh1, 32))
AddDataRow "desttbl", [rng1]`

Comment: @DigitalSea did you try filling `newdata` with a range? It does not matter whether the range has one or several rows.

Comment: There is the check for the `header` missing as in [JMax answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8295620/1705829).

Comment: @DigitalSea you are right, it adds one row and not more. Maybe because `lastrow` is a range of one row.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Sheets("Sheet-Name")
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Ws.ListObjects("Table-Name")
Dim newrow As ListRow
Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add

With newrow

        .Range(1, Ws.Range("Table-Name[Table-Column-Name]").Column) = "Your Data"

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Working solution **without named table**

##### Assumptions

- quick and dirty
- src and destination - dest - sheet with one table on it each
- Copy data from one sheet to another
- fixed static rows in `dest_last_row` for the header, not dynamic.

  ```
  Sub copy()

    With thisworkbook.sheets(1)
    src_last_row = .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set src_rng = .Range(.Cells(2, .columns("a").column), .Cells(src_last_row, 
    .Range("b" & 1).Column))
    End With

    With thisworkbook.Sheets(2)
      dest_last_row = .Range("a" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      if dest_last_row =3 then
        dest_last_row=2 
      end if

      Set dest_rng = .Range(.Cells(dest_last_row + 1, 1), .Cells(src_last_row + dest_last_row+1, .Range("b" & 1).Column))

      src_rng.Copy dest_rng
    End With

  End Sub
  ```

##### Disadvantage to the other answers with named table

- You need fixed static rows as used in `dest_last_row`...
- less intuitive

##### Advantage

- Copy several rows - real range - not just one row
- no need to learn the named table way