# How to merge formatting in VBA after copying data from one spreadsheet to another?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I'm using this code to transfer invoice data in one sheet to invoice history in another sheet and it is working as intended. However, I cannot figure out how to transfer said data to the invoice history sheet without ruining the formatting of the table. The picture below shows what happens when the data is entered manually versus when the code is used (last three rows).

```
 

  Dim xNew As Worksheet             'New Invoice Sheet              

  Dim xInvoices As Worksheet        'Invoice History Sheet    

  Dim iCurrentRow As Integer

  Set xNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New_Invoice")

  Set xInvoices = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoices")

  iCurrentRow = xInvoices.Cells(xInvoices.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   
 With xInvoices

    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 2) = xNew.Range("F5")

    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 3) = xNew.Range("B9")

    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 4) = xNew.Range("Total")

    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 5) = "Not Paid"

    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 6) = "Outright"

    .Cells(iCurrentRow, 7) = Date + 1
    
 End With
```

[image]

Comment: Is your data formatted as a ListObject?  If Yes then maybe look at Geoff's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295276/function-or-sub-to-add-new-row-and-data-to-table

Comment: So, is it a `ListObject` involved, as you say (mentioning a Table), or you simple formatted the range in that way?

Answer (score 0):

You did not answered the clarification question, but if there is a real `ListObject` in the sheet you try pasting below its last row, please try the next code:

```
Sub testLstRTable()
   Dim xNew As Worksheet, xInvoices As Worksheet, firstR As Long, lastR As Long, tb As ListObject
   
   Set xNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New_Invoice")
   Set xInvoices = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoices")
   Set tb = xInvoices.ListObjects("YourTable") 'use here your real table name!!!
   firstR = tb.HeaderRowRange.row 'for the case when the table header row is not the first...
   lastR = tb.ListRows.count + firstR
   xInvoices.Range(xInvoices.cells(lastR + 1, 2), xInvoices.cells(lastR + 1, 7)).value = _
                Array(xNew.Range("F5").value, xNew.Range("B9").value, xNew.Range("Total").value, "Not Paid", "Outright", Date + 1)
End Sub
```

Please, pay attention to changing the Table name, using the one existing in the involved sheet.

But if you name a simple formatted range as a table, please use the next code variant:

```
Sub testKeepFormat()
   Dim xNew As Worksheet, xInvoices As Worksheet, lastR As Long
   
   Set xNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New_Invoice")
   Set xInvoices = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoices")

   lastR = xInvoices.Range("B" & xNew.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   With xInvoices.Range(xInvoices.cells(lastR + 1, 2), xInvoices.cells(lastR + 1, 7))
        .value = Array(xNew.Range("F5").value, xNew.Range("B9").value, xNew.Range("Total").value, "Not Paid", "Outright", Date + 1)
        .Interior.Color = .Offset(-2).Interior.Color
        .cells(1, 2).HorizontalAlignment = .Offset(-2).cells(1, 2).HorizontalAlignment
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Alex Didn't you find some time to check the above suggestion(s)? If tested, didn't any of them solve your problem? If this is the situation, can you answer the question regarding the `ListObject` existence?

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Row Data Using Insert

- This will use the formatting of the last row.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RecordNewInvoice()
    
    Const sName As String = "NewInvoice"
    Const dName As String = "Invoices"
    Const dCol As String = "B"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim RowData As Variant: RowData = GetRowData(sws)
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dCol).End(xlUp)
    dCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
    dCell.Offset(1).Resize(, UBound(RowData)).Value = RowData

End Sub

Function GetRowData( _
    sws As Worksheet) _
As Variant
    Dim RowData(1 To 6) As Variant
    RowData(1) = sws.Range("F5").Value
    RowData(2) = sws.Range("B9").Value
    RowData(3) = sws.Range("Total").Value
    RowData(4) = "Not Paid"
    RowData(5) = "Outright"
    RowData(6) = Date + 1
    GetRowData = RowData
End Function
```